# lightdm-kde-greeter on multiseat do to let two simultaneous users login

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, login, lightdm, multiseat

I have two graphics cards, two monitors and some pairs of input devices. Till weeks ago they were working fine. Also with two simultaneous user logins.
Now they behave strange:

- When user1 logins on one seat (does not matter which) it does not let neither user1 nor userX login from the second seat.
- Logging off from that login'ed user logins that user automatically.

I have to mention that `lightdm-kde-greeter` was not found in the official Ubuntu repo. It was installed with

```
dpkg -i lightdm-kde-greeter_0.3.2.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

from the previous version.
What can I do?

**EDIT**

1. It has to be something with lightdm or policies limiting lightdm because I 
   installed also lightdm-webkit-greeter and have similar problems.
2. according to second bullet, alternative is to use `loginctl kill-user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems problem appears when updating packages and it is not meant to have on system both packages.

```
libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5
```

Solution is simple removing first one (obsolete). Simple as that.